# how to write $\nabla(1/f)$ ???

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have to prove that $\nabla(1/f)= -(1/f^2) \nabla (f) $.
I know that in general, we have $\nabla(fg)= \nabla(f) g+ \nabla(g)f$ and i have tried to write $g=1/f^2 $ which gives me $\nabla(1/f)= (1/f^2)\nabla(f) + f \nabla(1/f^2)$

any ideas how i can conclude?
(f and g are in $\mathbb{R}^n$)
thanks.

Comment: How do you show that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(\frac{1}{f(x)})=-\frac{1}{f^2(x)}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(f(x))$ for functions of one variable?

Comment: because $ d/dx(1/f(x))=  d/dx ( f(x)^{-1})= -1/f^2(x) d/dx (f(x)) $

Comment: but i do no know how to generalize it with more than 1 variable

Comment: Apply the product formula you stated to $g=1/f$.

Comment: @mathguy that is what i did, but i dont know how to show that $f\nabla(1/f^2)=-2/f^2 \nabla(f) $

Comment: What you did is not what I suggested. Plug in $1/f$ for $g$ directly in the product formula.

Comment: @mathguy what do you mean

Comment: You plugged in $g=1/f^2$, not $1/f$. Why?

Comment: i wanted to make 1/f^2 pop. but it does not work. However, with your suggestion @mathguy, it worked! Thanks a lot everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

Go component-wise:
$$
\partial_k (1/f) = \partial_k (f^{-1}) = (-1) f^{-2} \partial_k f = -(1/f^2) \partial_k f
$$
where $\partial_k = \partial / \partial x_k$.